# Sum solution unclear

Tags: algorithms

I have started studying algorithms and currently am reading Skiena's Algorithm Design book.
While doing the tasks, I encountered with question that I could not find solution for. I took a look in [solution](http://www.algorithm.cs.sunysb.edu/algowiki/index.php/TADM2E_2.3), but don't get how it is being solved.
Specifically line

> Now the third summation goes from j to i+j the formula on closer examination reveals that
>   $$\sum_{k=j}^{i+j}(j+i-k) \quad\text{ which  is}\quad  \sum_{k=1}^{i}(k)  $$

Can you explain to me how it could be transformed to this?

Comment: Intuitively, take a look at the values from the first and second sum. Hint: you might need to reverse the order.

Comment: The question is a little bit dishonest because the sum on the right should be $\sum_{k=0}^{i}(k)$. In this *particular* case it makes no difference (you are just adding an extra $0$ to the sum), but saying $k=1$ is confusing, deceptive, and unprofessional on the part of the author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=j}^{i+j}(j+i-k)&=(j+i)\sum_{k=j}^{i+j}1-\sum_{k=j}^{i+j}k\\
&=(j+i)\Big((i+j)-j+1\Big)-\sum_{k=j}^{i+j}k\\
&=(j+i)(i+1)-\frac{(i+j)-j+1}2\Big(j+(i+j)\Big)\\
&=(j+i)(i+1)-\frac{i+1}2(2j+i)\\
&=(i+1)\left((j+i)-\frac{2j+i}2\right)\\
&=(i+1)\frac{2j+2i-2j-i}2\\
&=(i+1)\frac{i}2\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^i k.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate why $ \sum_{k=j}^{i+j}k\ \ \ is \ \ \frac{(i+j)-j+1}2\Big(j+(i+j)\Big)\\ $ ? I do not follow this transformation

Comment: @Heisenberg do you know how to evaluate expressions of the form $\sum_{k=a}^bk$?

Comment: Thanks, You are completely right.

Answer (score 1):

If
$$ 
\hat{k} = T(k) =  j+i - k,
$$
then
$$
\sum_{k=j}^{i+j} j+i - k = \sum_{\hat{k}=T(j)}^{T(i+j)} \hat{k} = \sum_{\hat{k} = i}^0 \hat{k} = \sum_{\hat{k}=0}^i \hat{k} = \sum_{\hat{k}=1}^i \hat{k}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the $k$ with $s$ in the second sum, we have the sum $$\sum_{s=1}^{s=i}s=\sum_{s=i}^{s=1} s.$$ Let $s=j+i-k$. Then $s=i$ is equivalent to $k=j$ and $s=1$ is equivalent to $k=i+j-1$ so that $$\sum_{s=i}^{s=1} s=\sum_{k=j}^{k=i+j-1} (j+i-k)=\sum_{k=j}^{k=i+j} (j+i-k)$$

where the last equiality follows because when $k=i+j$ we have $j+i-k=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The solution should come to you intuitively if you just try plugging in some values in the summation and try to identify the pattern. Just put some values of k (say j, j+1, j+2 on one end and i+j, i+j-1, i+j-2 on the other end) This should give you the intuitive idea behind the simplification.